# Alexa Skill distribution Validation process

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Hello im working on a Skill for alexa using the lambda function

It works great but when it gets to validation it gives me some errors that im not able to pass..

last week i succeeded in passing the tests but seem i changed something on the build and now it dont pass thru it

My problem seems to be about the skill.json file

and the question is where it should located…

the skill is in portugueses and english and i added canada india england and australian english to the locales...

Since the code needed libraries im using visual studio code to upload the function to lambda directory

so the question is should i upload the files to only the lamda or also to the code area on the developer area? although its not accessible to code, the skill.json file (the updated version) seem to be sitting there somehow..

Any ideas? thanks

thanks!

What im trying is to change the location content of the skill but somehow it dont seem to do any

Answer (score -1):

I understand you that you are trying to add more locales to your skill.

In order to make your skill available for users on other locales, please add those locale to your skill by following the below steps:

1. Open the Alexa Developer Console: https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask
2. Search for the skill you want to publish in additional locales.
3. Every live skill contains a subversion that remains in the status "In Development". In this version you can add and test changes, before you resubmit an updated version of your skill to review again.
4. Once you find the subversion, click on "Edit".
5. At the top left you will be able to find a language menu with your current locale: "en-US". To see all supported languages, please click on that menu and select "Languages settings".
6. To add additional languages select the option "Add new language" and click on your desired locales. Click on "Save" to keep your changes.
7. You can now use the top left menu to switch between the different locales you just added to your skill.
8. For every added language, there is a completely new interaction model that needs to be prepared like you did for the previously en-US locale.
9. Once you have finished all the changes and additions you wanted to do for your skill, please remember to save the model and build it to save the changes.
10. Resubmit the In Dev skill for certification. Selecting "In all countries and regions where Amazon distributes skills", in the distribution section of the skill, is often the best option unless there is a good reason to limit your skill's availability. This will ensure that the skill is available for global distribution.

To speed up your development, I advise you to use the skill locale clone feature to extend that locale asset to another locale in the same language - this process creates a copy of your skill's manifest data and interaction model. The clone also copies the invocation name, API usage—such as Alexa Presentation Language (APL) or Account Linking—and endpoint URL. The skill locale clone feature supports all languages. However, the feature doesn’t support cross-language locale cloning. For example, you can't clone a skill from en-US to es-ES, but you can clone a locale from en-US to en-GB. Please follow this procedure - https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/develop-skills-in-multiple-languages.html#clone-a-skill-locale-with-the-developer-console

Using JSON editor: If you want to keep the same interaction model for all your English languages, you can go to the original interaction model of your skill and click on "JSON editor", after that you can copy all the code you have there and go to the same section ("JSON editor") in your new interaction models and paste it there. Take into consideration that each region should have its own endpoint in order to work properly.

You can find further information on how to develop skills in multiple languages here: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/develop-skills-in-multiple-languages.html